# C++ Write a function to input a list of numbers and print the frequency of the first input number

Tags: c++, arrays, function, user-input, frequency

I am trying to write a C++ program to ask user to input a list of 5 numbers and print out the counts of the first number in the input. I have been trying to use array[] but I have some problems. The ideal inputs and outputs are :

- Input : 1 1 2 3 1 Output: 3 because there are 3 counts of 1
- Input : 1 2 3 4 5 Output: 1
- Input : 1 1 1 0 0 Output: 3

Here are my codes, my code allows me to take the inputs but it does not do anything with it. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//frequency function
int frequency(int a[])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
       if (a[i] == a[0])
       {
          count++;
       }
    cout << count << endl ;
    return count;
}
 
// Driver program
int main() {

    int i; 
    cout << "Please enter your numbers: ";
    int a[5] = {a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]};
   for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) 
   {
    // Reading User Input value Based on index
    cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2]>> a[3] >> a[4];
    return 0;
   }

    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    cout << frequency(a);


}
```

I tried another simpler approach but it needs a little more help

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std ;
    
    int main(){
    cout << "Please enter your numbers: ";
    int a[5];
    int repeat;
    int first = a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
       // Reading User Input value Based on index
       cin >> a[i];
    
      }
    if (a[i] == first){
        repeat++; 
    }
    cout << "Count: " << repeat;
}
```

Comment: Your `return 0;` in `main()` is the reason your "code does no do anything with it".  Once you return, the function is finished.  Also, a question that does not ask any question is likely to be closed.  "Any help is appreciated" is not a clear or specific enough question for Stack Overflow.  It is more appropriate for a discussion forum.

Comment: What is your problem? What is your question? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you have an odd mixture of techniques for reading a set of numbers. You simply need

```
cout << "Please enter your numbers: ";
int a[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
   // Reading User Input value Based on index
   cin >> a[i];

  }
```

and you certainly dont want that `return` as it will end the program

you would be better off using `std::vector` then you would not need to hard code the array size.

Note at the moment you have 6 as the arrays size in 'frequency' but 5 in main